# TypeError: connect() argument 4 must be str, not WindowsPath

Tags: python, django

When I run this python manage.py migrate

```
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WyndhamKeitA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

**TypeError: connect() argument 4 must be str, not WindowsPath**
```

my DB under settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.crudpy',
        'USERNAME': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the error?

crudpy is the schema I've created on mysql

Comment: The default is: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')` so try `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.crudpy')`

Comment: yay, great! just really need to adjust because of the tutorial I am watching is bit old.